# Cannot access a docker hosted webserver from external network

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, docker, docker-compose

I’m in the process of migrating a small personal website from a virtualbox vm to a docker container that is hosted on my personal computer. But I get into an issue where I get a "connection timed out" when trying to reach that container from the internet (trying with my phone without wifi) it does work from other computers on the same network.

Here is what I did tests until now:

**Local network**

Everything work fine both using http://localhost and http://192.168.1.10 from any other computer on the network

I understand from that test that my computer and docker config are working fine for the server to be accessible from outside that computer.

**From internet**

On my internet gateway, I do have a port forward setup. When redirecting to 192.168.1.15                                                 I  do have access to the vm server correctly.

when redirecting to 192.168.1.10 I get the gateway timeout, <s>and port checking tool says that port 80 is closed</s>

I understand from that test that my ISP isn’t getting in the way and my gateway is properly forwarding the data to the right ip. Also not an issue on the client side (my phone/phone provider)

**usefull config**

- docker-compose config:

```
    version: "3.7"
    services:    
        proxy:
            image: nginx:stable
            ports:
                - "80:80"
            volumes:
                - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

- ./proxy/conf.d/site.conf

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;     # not actual DNS, but it doesn’t seem to be in cause.

        location / {
            deny all;
        }   
    }
```

> yes, *work fine* actually mean I get a 403 forbidden error right now

- gateway port forward (in a ui)    port 80 to port 80 host 192.168.10
- Virtualbox vm network is configured as bridge and has IP 192.168.1.15
- all internal IP written are static
  [image: topology]

Let me know if any other info might be required

**excluded**

I purposely excluded any ssl and DNS variable until that issue is resolved will be configured afterward.

I’m mainly looking at ideas of what else to checkups because all piece seem to work well individually but I’m obviously missing something.

edit:
looked a bit more into the closed port/timeout issue
output of curl command from a remote computer:

```
$  curl -v --output - 142.#.#.#
*   Trying 142.#.#.#:80...
* Connected to 142.#.#.# (142.#.#.#) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 142.#.#.#
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 502 Connection timed out
< Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2022 16:34:06 GMT
< Connection: close
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 219
< 
<HEAD><TITLE>Connection timed out</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
 Connection timed out</B></FONT>

<!-- default "Connection timed out" response (502) -->
</BODY>
* Closing connection 0
```

output of port check

```
$ nmap 142.#.#.# -p 81
...
Host is up (0.077s latency).

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp open     http


$ nc -zvw10 142.#.#.# 80
...
[142.#.#.#] 80 (http) open
```

but, ping.eu that I used first still show it as closed. Not sure how they are checking it

Comment: 'gateway timeout' is an http error generated by a http server acting as a proxy. If the port was closed your browser would not time out the connection attempt but directly throw an error. if the port was open and nobody answered your browser would time out the connection attempt. Means 'port checking tool says that port 80 is closed' together with 'gateway timeout' doesn't make sense.

Comment: I do agree, but it's the result that I get, which confuse me

Comment: @xenoson looked again at this closed port issue, and look like the first tool a was using gave a false negative, updated with the new info

Comment: How is the host PC connected to your home network, wired or wlan? Virtualbox uses some hacks to allow bridged mode over wifi. Could be the reason why it works there.

Comment: It's wired with static ip defined from the hosts (not dhcp assigned) it does have another dumb switch between the computer and the gateway. Might be worth mentioning the host is on Linux.